# Your export is incomplete due to a too slow execution time limit at PHP level

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

When I try to export a database sql file in phpmyadmin it fails. I get the following error:

`"Your output is incomplete, due to a low execution time limit on PHP level".`

I don't know what to do..

Comment: _due to a low execution time limit on PHP level..._ you have to increase the execution time in php.ini

Comment: You have copied/pasted exactly the same content of an existing question, although it has been answered, why?

Comment: no i have issue with my export data base in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

edit maximum execution time in php.ini. look for this line 'max_execution_time' set the time in seconds